# How to debug truffle compile obscure error - run.js:51:1 at <anonymous>

Tags: truffle

Trying to compile an out of the box project (simple clone) and getting this obscure error... Any suggestions on how to debug this, turn on compiler verbosity etc?

```
truffle compile    
...
<long list of compiled items>
...
Compilation failed. See above.
        at run (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\compile-solidity\run.js:51:1)
        at <anonymous>
    Truffle v5.1.45 (core: 5.1.45)
```

Comment: Did you look at the "long list of compiled items" if there's an error?

Comment: No errors in the compiled list

Answer (score 0):

Updating my node.js (8.9.4) to latest LTS (12.18.4) solved the issue.